# PyQt5 top row of QFormLayout not responding to mouse click

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

Using QtDesigner and PyQt5 with pyuic5 I'm setting up a FormLayout with a variable number of rows.
Each row is a custom widget created in QtDesigner, consisting of a QLabel and a QHBoxLayout containing a QLineEdit and QPushButton.

I create the row UI using

```
    def get_data_widget(parent=None, **kwargs):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent)
        dlg_ui = wgtDataRow.Ui_Form()       # from the custom made widget
        dlg_ui.setupUi(widget)
    
        # recursively ensure all objectName()s are unique
        rename_widget(widget, "_%s" % unique_id())
    
        dlg_ui.label.setText(kwargs.get('name') or '')
        dlg_ui.editData.setText(kwargs.get('value') or '')
    
        return dlg_ui
```

The row UI is inserted in the QFormLayout in a QDialog method:

```
    def add_data_entry_row(self, name, **kwargs):
        # simplified code, but this is the bit that affects the QFormLayout
        posn = kwargs.get('position', 0)
        data_ui = get_data_widget(self, name=name, value=kwargs.get('value'))
        self.dlg_ui.formLayout.insertRow(posn, data_ui.label, data_ui.widget)
```

The problem I have is that the first row of the QFormLayout is not responding to the mouse clicks.

If I insert a new row at 0 the previously unresponsive row is moved down and becomes responsive and the new (top) row unresponsive.

Can anyone throw any light on this?

Comment: OK, curiouser and curiouser.
If I expand the containing dialog, after a brief interval the top row QPushButton responds to the mouse click but the QLineEdit remains unresponsive

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Murphy strikes again! I've spent some time setting up a minimal example, though it's not that minimal with the code generated by pyuic5 and, of course,  everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to generate a minimal example which had the same problem I found the cause. Basically I was making changes to the UI before executing show()
What I had (code minimised for clarity)

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.dlg_ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.dlg_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setModal(True)
        
        self.init_ui(**kwargs)  # load the UI widgets with data
        
        self.show()
```

which should have been

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.dlg_ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.dlg_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setModal(True)
        
        self.show()  # excute BEFORE loading the UI
        
        self.init_ui(**kwargs)  # load the UI widgets with data
```